# TypeScript. Как указать указать тип свойству объекта внутри функции

Tags: typescript, типы

Только начал изучать TS и в ступор привела такая мелкая функция и я никак не могу допереть, что тут делать.
Есть функция:

```
export const compareNumeric = (a: object, b: object, property: string) => {
  if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1;
  if (a[property] == b[property]) return 0;
  if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
  }
```

TypeScript  выдаёт ошибку:

```
    TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression 
  of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' 
  was found on type '{}'.
```

Я пробовал выставлять `a[property]: any`, и другие вариации, но результат не меняется.

Полагаю я синтаксически, что то не так указываю, но гугл не дал нужного результата.

Как правильно выставить тип?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была из-за того, что интерпретатор хочет знать, что ключи являются именно строкой.
Вот в итоге как это решил:

```
export const compareNumeric = (
  a: {[key: string]: any} \\Указываем интерпритатору
  b: {[key: string]: any}, \\Указываем интерпритатору
  property: string) => {
if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1;
  if (a[property] == b[property]) return 0;
  if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню что лучше бы для таких функций использовать дженерики, тогда они смогут работать с любыми объектами и будут проверять наличие в них указанного свойства.

Пример:

```typescript
function compareNumeric<
    K extends string,
    T1 extends Record<K, number>,
    T2 extends Record<K, number>
>(a: T1, b: T2, property: K) {
    const difference = a[property] - b[property];

    if (difference > 0) return 1;
    if (difference < 0) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь мы задаём множество строковых ключей `K` и 2 различных типа объектов, каждый из которых обязан иметь свойсва из `K` типа `number`. Таким образом мы получим ошибку компиляции если передадим объекты у которых нет нужных свойств или имеющие неверный тип указанного свойства.